# mongoose populate() method returns only the matcher

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

In my chats collection I am saving the user ids of the participants. My `chats` Collection looks like below,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("650328b3737c451a142aeb7d"),
    "users" : [
        ObjectId("636fb2405abcae00169e0124"),
        ObjectId("636e8c57b539cf0720193b6d")
    ],
    "chatName" : "sender",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-09-14T15:37:23.472+0000"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2023-09-14T15:37:23.472+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Now when I execute `Chat.find({ users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user.id } } })`, I get below response with participant user ids in users array.

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            "636fb2405abcae00169e0124",
            "636e8c57b539cf0720193b6d"
        ],
        "_id": "65032aa69ed7f62aeca36e33",
        "chatName": "sender",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:42.585Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:57.205Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "latestMessage": "65032ab49ed7f62aeca36e37"
    }
]
```

Adding the `populate()` function like `.populate("users", "-password -activationCode")` by chaining after `find()` method gives back only the `req.user.id` object as expanded.

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
                "isActive": true,
                "_id": "636e8c57b539cf0720193b6d",
                "name": "Rajen Viswakarma",
                "email": "agent@gmail.com",
                "usertype": "agent",
                "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/ac1b0399de42434499d937b58796a210?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
                "date": "2022-11-11T17:54:31.421Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ],
        "_id": "65032aa69ed7f62aeca36e33",
        "chatName": "sender",
        "createdAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:42.585Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:57.205Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "latestMessage": {
            "readBy": [],
            "_id": "65032ab49ed7f62aeca36e37",
            "content": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "chat": "65032aa69ed7f62aeca36e33",
            "createdAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:56.386Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-14T15:45:56.386Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Please help. TIA.

Comment: for someone trying to replicate https://shorturl.at/ghLNV

Comment: I suspect you have no user with `ObjectId` = `636fb2405abcae00169e0124`. Can you confirm you have user with that `_id` in your database?

Comment: @jQueeny I think, you are correct. I was unable to find an user with that id in my `users` collection. Thanks 

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for commenting to confirm as some users leave the question hanging. Good luck with your project.